# How can I make "Add event..." use the default Calendar of 16.04?

Tags: indicator, calendar

**Add event:**

[image]

**Default Calendar app in Ubuntu 16.04:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a clarification : the first screenshot in your question shows the `datetime` indicator. The second screenshot in your question shows the  `GNOME Calendar` application. To add a new event open the Calendar application and click on **Calendar** -> **Add event...** in the app menu bar.

[image]

As there is no official possibility to add a new event by using the indicator - that's the way to go ...

[image]

An alternative might be to write a script (officially not supported) for this functionality of course.

Comment: Thank you @cl-netbox! Let me clarify my question. I want that, if I click on Add event in the indicator-datetime, it opens the new event pop-up from the Calendar application. This is not possible without a script, correct?

Comment: @orschiro : Yes, you understood it correctly, unfortunately it is not possible to do this without a script. I understood your question and that is why I answered it this way - the official possibility to add an event and the unofficial possibility by using a script. Hope that I could clarify the matter and help you a bit ... :)

Comment: thanks! Yes, you did. :) Let's continue with this [feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1577836) then.